# Im using SDL and my program use CPU a lot

Tags: sdl

how can I use graphic card instead of CPU when I call SDL functions?

Comment: Well, we can't help you much if we don't see the source...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot, SDL is only a software renderer. However, you can use SDL to create a window, catch events and then you can perform your drawing using OpenGL.

If your program is eating 100 % CPU, make sure that you limit the FPS correctly (by adding SDL_Delay to the main loop).

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you can use SDL2.0.
That supports Full 3D hardware acceleration using SDL1.2 similar functions.

http://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide

Answer (score 0):

In SDL 2.0, create your renderer with SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED and SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC flags. First one implies hardware acceleration when possible, and second limits your program to run 60(depends on monitor's refresh rate) fps at most, thus freeing CPU from continuous work.